# Изменение границ тега input после заполнения

Tags: javascript, css

```
    <form>
  <label for="fname" id="name">ИМЯ</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""/>

  <label for="fphone" id="name">телефон</label>
  <input type="text" id="fphone" name="fphone" value="+11111111111"/>

  <input type="submit" value="отправить"/>


</form>
```

надо изменить нижний бордер input после его заполнения

```
 var input = document.body;
input.oninput = function() {
   this.style.borderbottom = "#ccffcc";
};
```

пытаюсь использовать что то типа такого , но не получается , помогите пожалуйста

Comment: var input = document.body; - вы вешаете обработчики и меняете границу у body

Comment: а как тогда поменять у input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в коде несколько ошибок.

1. Нет свойства в `style` `borderbottom`. Есть `borderBottom`
2. Значение `borderBottom` формируется так: `1px solid #fff` (к примеру, то есть состоит из комбинации свойств `border-width`, `border-style`, `border-color` и т.д)
3. Даже если Вы всё исправите будет краситься `body` а не `input`, так как Вы вешаете событие на него, используйте `e.target`(код ниже) или лучше `document.querySelectorAll(input)` и вешать обработчики на полученные поля ввода формы.

Рабочий код ниже

```js
var input = document.body;
input.oninput = function(e) {
 e.target.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #ccffcc";
 //this.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #ccffcc";
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname" id="name">ИМЯ</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="">

  <label for="fphone" id="name">телефон</label>
  <input type="text" id="fphone" name="fphone" value="+11111111111">

<input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а по поводу style , я просто протупил и забыл про 1px solid. Очень много навалилось на меня за последние два дня. С трудом работаю , поэтому вот так и выходит , что даже стили у границ забываю ставить

Comment: @XXXXXX рад помочь)

Comment: спасибо большое . Сейчас уже другая проблема. наложил картинку на картинку , дал им абсолют и везде по 0 , и он уехал наверх из за этого ..класс ...офигено , лучше просто не бывает. Еще раз  спасибо большое)